# Блокировка базы данных при помощи Sympfony

Tags: база-данных, symfony

Я работаю со страницей которую кто-то до меня создал при помощи Symfony Framework. Мне необходимо настроить правила доступа к базе данных. А именно:
Как только один пользователь начинает редактировать какую нибудь запись, то любому другому, пытающемуся отредактировать эту же запись, высвечивается соответствующее сообщение.

Как это можно реализовать при помощи Symfony? Важно, что бы обязательно выскакивало сообщение.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну например добавить в нужную модель поле "редактируется". По кнопке редактировать сначала смотрите это поле и если есть флаг - выдаете сообщение. По кнопке сохранить флаг снимаете. Вот только как отслеживать незавершенное редактирование  - вопрос. Возможно по тайм-ауту флаг  снимать.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но это универсальное решение. Я ожидал подсказку, как это делается в symfony и возможно ли вообще. Там такой код, такая структура, что я неделю буду с ним возиться. Может можно как-то через symfony реализовать. Я имею в виду где-нибудь в config файле дописать какую нибудь строчку и откомпилировать всё и всё будет работать как надо.

Comment: Обратите внимание на компонент workflow , это не совсем то что вам нужно, однако возможно поможет. 
Может кто еще что то знает на эту тему, самому было бы интересно посмотреть как решаются подобные задачи не "в ручную".